# "window is not defined" error on Meteor Todo tutorial with Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, meteor

I want to get started with Meteor using Angular2. So I followed the [official Meteor tutorial for a simple Todo App](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/angular/templates) until step 2.7 where a new project is created, with Angular as template engine instead of the default blaze from Meteor.

I EXACTLY followed the steps in the tutorial 3 times, each time with a new project. But It seems impossible to get it work! When I start the application, I got the following error:

```
C:\Users\MyUser\WebstormProjects\my-meteor-project2>meteor
[[[[[ C:\Users\MyUser\WebstormProjects\my-meteor-project2 ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
W20170826-17:58:26.182(2)? (STDERR) C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.5.1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:280
W20170826-17:58:26.261(2)? (STDERR)                                             throw(ex);
W20170826-17:58:26.264(2)? (STDERR)                                             ^
W20170826-17:58:26.265(2)? (STDERR)
W20170826-17:58:26.266(2)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: window is not defined
W20170826-17:58:26.267(2)? (STDERR)     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\MyUser\WebstormProjects\my-meteor-project2\node_modules\angular\angular.js:33887:4)
W20170826-17:58:26.270(2)? (STDERR)     at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
W20170826-17:58:26.272(2)? (STDERR)     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
W20170826-17:58:26.273(2)? (STDERR)     at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
W20170826-17:58:26.275(2)? (STDERR)     at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
W20170826-17:58:26.276(2)? (STDERR)     at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
W20170826-17:58:26.277(2)? (STDERR)     at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
W20170826-17:58:26.279(2)? (STDERR)     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\MyUser\WebstormProjects\my-meteor-project2\node_modules\angular\index.js:1:1)
W20170826-17:58:26.282(2)? (STDERR)     at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
W20170826-17:58:26.283(2)? (STDERR)     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
=> Exited with code: 1
```

It seems that the server try to access the `window` object, which exists on the client only I think. But as a newbie, I have no clue why this happens, and what I have to do here, since the tutorial doesn't seem to have any information for this issue.

Comment: How is your current folder structure? If you want code to run only on the client, then put that in a directory called client (eg. ```/client/index.js```) OR wrap the code in a ```if(Meteor.isClient){...}``` block

Comment: @blueren The same as described here: https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/angular/creating-an-app I placed the `imports` directory in the root folder. According to the description in the tutorial, this seems right. Or do I have to place it in the `client` directory?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/angular/testing

> 11.6  Prepare the component for each test imports/components/todosList/**client**/todosList.tests.js »

So @blueren is correct, the tutorials aren't that clear on emphasizing the importance of folder structure

Once I created a client folder and directed it there, it ran correctly
(answering this old question because I ran into this myself in 2021)